# Middleware DI Error

Tags: c#, dependency-injection, asp.net-core

I am attempting to implement the API Key Validator mentioned in this [post](http://www.mithunvp.com/write-custom-asp-net-core-middleware-web-api/).  I am running into an issue where the injected service I am using to do validation in the middleware class is returning:

*InvalidOperationException: Cannot resolve 'FoosballKeepr.Services.Interfaces.ILeagueService' from root provider because it requires scoped service 'FoosballKeepr.Data.FoosballKeeprContext'.*

I believe I am registering my dbContext, services, and repositories correctly in Startup.cs.

```
public class Startup
{
    public Startup(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        Configuration = configuration;
    }

    public IConfiguration Configuration { get; }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to add services to the container.
    public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
    {
        //MVC
        services.AddMvc();

        //Database
        var connection = @"Server=localhost\SQLEXPRESS;Database=FoosballKeepr;Trusted_Connection=True;";
        services.AddDbContext<FoosballKeeprContext>(options => options.UseSqlServer(connection));

        //Services
        services.AddTransient<IPlayerService, PlayerService>();
        services.AddTransient<ILeagueService, LeagueService>();

        //Repositories
        services.AddTransient<IPlayerRepository, PlayerRepository>();
        services.AddTransient<ILeagueRepository, LeagueRepository>();
    }

    // This method gets called by the runtime. Use this method to configure the HTTP request pipeline.
    public void Configure(IApplicationBuilder app, IHostingEnvironment env)
    {
        if (env.IsDevelopment())
        {
            app.UseDeveloperExceptionPage();
        }

        app.UseMiddleware<ApiKeyValidatorMiddleware>();

        app.UseMvc();
    }
}
```

Custom middleware validator:

```
public class ApiKeyValidatorMiddleware
{
    private readonly RequestDelegate _next;
    private ILeagueService _leagueService;

    public ApiKeyValidatorMiddleware(RequestDelegate next, ILeagueService leagueService)
    {
        _next = next;
        _leagueService = leagueService;
    }

    public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context)
    {
        if (!context.Request.Headers.Keys.Contains("x-api-key"))
        {
            context.Response.StatusCode = 400;              
            await context.Response.WriteAsync("API Key Missing.");
            return;
        }
        else
        {
            int leagueId = _leagueService.ValidateApiKey(context.Request.Headers["x-api-key"]);

            if (leagueId == 0)
            {
                context.Response.StatusCode = 401;
                await context.Response.WriteAsync("Invalid API Key");
                return;
            }
            else
            {
                context.Items["LeagueId"] = leagueId;
            }
        }

        await _next.Invoke(context);
    }
}
```

Service

```
    public class LeagueService : ILeagueService
{
    private readonly ILeagueRepository _leagueRepository;

    public LeagueService(ILeagueRepository leagueRepository)
    {
        _leagueRepository = leagueRepository;
    }

    public int ValidateApiKey(string apiKey)
    {
        return _leagueRepository.ValidateApiKey(apiKey);
    }
}
```

Repository

```
public class LeagueRepository : ILeagueRepository
{
    private readonly FoosballKeeprContext _context;

    public LeagueRepository(FoosballKeeprContext context)
    {
        _context = context;
    }

    public int ValidateApiKey(string apiKey)
    {
        var query = from l in _context.League
                    where l.ApiKey == apiKey
                    select l.LeagueId;

        return query.FirstOrDefault();
    }
}
```

This is my first time implementing custom middleware functionality so I feel like my issue is not correctly setting something up in the correct context, but nothing is popping up as obvious.  Does this look familiar to anyone??

Comment: As a side note: unless you have a specific reason (i.e will ditch EF in the future) to put EF behind a Repository, don't do it. Another note: EF6 and EF Core contain `Async` methods for I/O-bound operations, you should use them instead of the synchronous version. Yet another note (which might solve your issue), your services and repositories should be `AddScoped` rather than `AddTransient`

Comment: Just a thought but would it make a difference if `services.AddTransient<ILeagueRepository, LeagueRepository>();` was before `services.AddTransient<ILeagueService, LeagueService>();` since the service is dependent on the repository.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto what's wrong with putting EF behind a repository. It abstracts the logic and give simple methods to call to access the data.

Comment: @pmcilreavy The problem is that most people get it wrong, becoming a huge maintenance burden, and EF already implements both Repository (`DbContext` itself) and Unit Of Work (each `DbSet`). EF is extremely simple, I don't know how you could make it simpler by hiding it behind yet another layer.

Comment: @SBFrancies I tried re-ordering an still received the exact same error.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto After changing the services and repository registrations to AddScoped, I know receive:  
_InvalidOperationException: Cannot resolve scoped service 'FoosballKeepr.Services.Interfaces.ILeagueService' from root provider._  So that at least cleared up the dbContext scope issue.  Now it appears it just doesn't like the initial usage/register of the service itself.

Comment: @CamiloTerevinto Not really sure that's a reason. Many people get EF wrong and return IQueryables into logic that ends up being a maintenance and debugging headache. People repeat queries in multiple places etc. My point is you can't just say blanket rule is don't use repository pattern with EF.

Comment: @pmcilreavy I said unless there's a reason. If you don't check for code duplicates the same will happen with a repository. It really doesn't change anything since, as I stated, EF is already a repository. People failing to understand `IQueryable` is a completely different topic, and I've even seen repositories that return `IQueryable`, since it's a LINQ concept not an EF one

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The problem is that middlewares don't have a scope, given that:

> [Middleware is constructed once per application lifetime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/middleware?tabs=aspnetcore2x)

So, when you need to inject scoped services, you do it at the `Invoke` operation (what's known as method injection):

```
public async Task Invoke(HttpContext context, ILeagueService service)
{
    //...
}
```

Comment: Yes this was the issue!  Thanks so much, I'll take a closer look at that middleware article as well as look over my data design pattern as you mentioned above.

Comment: And if you have optional dependencies, you can get them via `context.RequestServices`.